# Trying to convert yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss-07:00 to correct time in Android

Tags: java, android, jodatime

Okay, so here's my issue in Android right now. On our Database there's a timestamp in this format `8/15/2013 2:00:48 PM` and through a .NET WebService I get that same time like this in Android: `2013-08-15T14:00:48-07:00`. Now I want to convert this format into a Date Time format that I can use for comparison (for example this webservice provides every instance where a device failed at logging in so we want to check the amount of time between occurances to see if there's any issues). Below I have this code where I'm trying to use JODA Time but it's still not returning the correct format:

```
public static Date convertStringToDate(String input)  {
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
    DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(input);
    return dateTime.toDate();
    //printout shows: Thu Aug 15 17:00:48 EDT 2013
}
```

I know that the server is returning some crappy time format that is hard to work with (it took a while to get this to work in the iOS App we have, and even there it's still rather clunky) so I don't mind changing the webservice or the query if that would make things easier.

Comment: What it's your question? Because your output shows the same time. EDT it's -04:00

Comment: Ha, I didn't realize that EDT is -4:00. But I guess one question is there a way for me to format it to display as '8/15/2013 2:00:48 PM' for example (there's a few places where I need to put the actual time and others where it's just used in the background so it doesn't matter there). Thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'it`s not returning correct format'? You want to parse the `String` to `Date` so what 'returning` format do you mean?

Comment: Not sure that this really should be tagged SQL Server... you have a string of a certain format after it comes through your web service, and your problem wouldn't change if it ultimately came from SQL Server, Oracle, a text file, your desktop, an e-mail, etc.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I only put that tag in since I wasn't sure if there was something that could have been done on the Server side or if this was strictly an issue with the receiving side. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understand is that you have your correct instance of date already and what you need is to parse it to String.

I suggest you use:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
//this will give you the format '8/15/2013 2:00:48 PM'

String d = formatter.format(date);
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Also seams you want to have your date instance in -07:00 timezone
So you can change your line

```
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(input);
```

for

```
DateTime dateTime = formatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("-07:00")).parseDateTime(input);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a very similar format, and I parse it using SimpleDateFormat, try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ", Locale.US);
Date dateTime = format .parse(value);
```